# adding a where clause to sql statement

Tags: zend-framework2

I am trying to filter data from a table using sql as follows:

```
$select= new \Zend\Db\Sql\Select ;
$select->from('questions');
$select->where(array('questions.id'=>$value));
$select->columns(array('user_id','description'));

$select->join('users', "users.id = questions.user_id",  array('username','password'), 'left'); 
echo $select->getSqlString(); 

$resultSet = $this->tableGateway->selectWith($select);

return $resultSet;
```

Without the `$select->where(array('questions.id'=>$value));` the query executes okay and i can get all database values. Otherwise if i add the statement i get this error:

```
Attempting to quote a value without specific driver level support 
can introduce security vulnerabilities in a production environment.
```

How can i rectify this for the where clause to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll probably find that it's echoing the SQL string which is generating that error. Assuming you only did that for debugging, removing that line should fix it. Alternatively you can pass the platform object to the function with something like:

```
echo $select->getSqlString($this->tableGateway->getAdapter()->getPlatform());
```

Comment: yeah..it works but was just a little bit worried about that statement.thanks alot.

Comment: I think it means the select object doesn't know how to quote values in your query since the select object on its own doesn't know what type of database you're using. When the query is eventually run it's done using the database adapter, which does know the type of DB.